# what is the equivalent of "-" in an url?

Tags: android

How to change - in url.
I have got the same problem with space so i changed it with %20 and it worked:

```
name = name.replaceAll(" ","%20");
```

What is the equivalent of "-" in an url?

I tried %2C and it doesn't word: %2C -> ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the dash char is considered a safe char in the URL. If you have problems, then the problems might have nothing to do with the dash. Try, though, to replace it with %2D.

Answer (score 2):

Use URLEncoder.encode(String s) to encode all your strings that you are gonna use for urls.

Comment: You mean, use `URLEncoder.encode` to encode strings that you are gonna *put inside URLs*. If you encode the entire URL, it will no longer be a URL. That's the whole idea of the encoding process - get rid of characters that have special meaning in an URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's the ascii code ([translator](http://www.idea2ic.com/PlayWithJavascript/hexToAscii.html)). `-` translates to `%2d`. You were close :)